# Log response of HttpResponse then process

Tags: android, httpresponse

How can I log a response from `HttpResponse` and then process the response after.

for example when I do this

```
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
String xml = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

i get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed`

because I wrote the entity to a string. I only want to use that string for debugging and then use the InputStream to process all the content in the response

Comment: what's "resp" in your code? would u modify it so that I can test it and give you the answer?

Comment: @ErfanMowlaei reps is `HttpResponse`

Comment: Please edit your code so that I can run it and solve your problem

Comment: what more code do you need, all the required information is right there

Comment: initial part for resp

Comment: Well it is clearly not possible to read the response twice. So you have to come up with something different. For instance use the xml to parse.

Comment: @ErfanMowlaei I am not posting my Web service method, for everyone to see. It is not required to provide an answer

Comment: @greenapps which is why I am asking the question, how can I log and process the response

Comment: dude just use a simple site (like google) so that I know what you have done back there and I can run your code.

Comment: Not in the way you do now. So come up with something where you read the stream once. (By the way: you posted enough code to demonstrate your problem).

Comment: @greenapps yes I realize that, I am asking for solutions to that problem

Comment: I already gave you one. If you don't want that way then only read the inputstream and while doing that process and log piece by piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
String asString = getString(is);
Log.i(TAG,""+asString);
```

The point is to avoid closing the `InputStream` with `is.close()` or flushing it with `is.flush()`, to have it later for processing. The exception is thrown because the content is converted as `InputStream` by calling `EntityUtils.toString(entity);`

```
public static String getString( InputStream is) throws IOException {
        int ch;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((ch = is.read())!= -1)
            sb.append((char)ch);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Don't forget to close the stream after you are done with the processing.

Comment: OP never stated this.

Comment: You could read all in the original error quote and the discussion i had with the OP before you came with an answer.

Comment: Is it hard for you to see that OP never said anything about how many times he has to consume the stream or any performance constrains? By the comments, you are the one suggesting reading the stream once, which doesn't mean is the only solution, and doesn't make my answer nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a code block that can be used to convert an `HttpResponse` into a `String`:

```
String output = inputStreamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

public static StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is){
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb;
}
```